# setDoc() Called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a new firestore document when someone subscribes to my api plan. I want the document id to be the customer id, but i ran into this error.

While the setDoc documentation says that if the document can't be found it will be created with the providing document id. So here is my code:

```js
import { db } from './resources/firebase.js';
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

await setDoc(doc(db, "customers", customerId), {
                key: hashedApiKey,
                itemId: itemID,
                active: true,
                calls: 0
            });
```

and here is a screenshot of the firestore side:
[image]
The current entry is just a test value.

Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it is most probably because the value of one of the fields of the document to be saved is undefined, i.e. `hashedApiKey` or `itemID`. You should debug your code by printing the values of these two variables.